# How to add a row in table and submit form post data

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to add a row of elements in the table , the jQuery code is working, I can add row as many as I want, but the problem is when I submit the rows data, I get only the first elements (first row), so what I am missing here?

html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'step2_ach'%}" >
      {% csrf_token %}
    <button id="done" class="btn btn-primary disabled" name="submit" type="submit">Ajouter</button>
      <tr>

          <td name="nadjib1">
                 <select  required="true" name="article" id="article" class="form-control">
                 <option selected></option>
                        {% for obj in art %}
                 <option  value="{{obj}}">{{obj}}</option>
                         {%endfor%}

             </select>

          </td>
          <td>
                 <input class="na"  required="true" min="0" step="0.01"
                        type="number" id="prix"  name="prix" placeholder="0.00">
          </td>
          <td>
                 <input class="qu l" required="true" pattern="\d+" type="number" id="quantite" name="quantite">
          </td>
      </tr>


</form>
```

jQuery :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add").click(function() {
          $('#book-table tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#book-table tbody>tr:last');
          return false;
        });
    });
```

views.py

```
ef step2_ach(request):
   ach = Achats.objects.latest('id')
   Art = Article.objects.all()
   if request.method == 'POST':
       if   request.POST['article'] and request.POST['prix'] and request.POST['quantite']:
         prix = float(request.POST['prix'] )
         prix = str(round(prix ,2))
         artt = get_object_or_404(Article,Description = request.POST['article'])
         for article in request.POST.getlist('quantite'):
             na = AssociationForm({'Id_Article' :artt ,'Id_Achats':Achats.objects.latest('id'),'Prix_Unitaire':prix,'Quantite':request.POST['quantite']},instance=Association())
             na.save()
         return redirect('view')
       else:
           error = 'please check your inputs ! '
           return render(request, 'step2.html', { 'art': Art , 'er': error })

   return render(request, 'step2.html', {'id_achat':ach , 'art': Art})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you clone the row, you get elements with duplicate ids, but ids have to be unique. Try to adjust your function to add rows like this:

```
 $("#add").click(function() {
    let clone = $('#book-table tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
    var count = $("#book-table tbody tr").length;
    clone.find("[id^='article']").attr("id", "article" + count);
    clone.find("[id^='prix']").attr("id", "prix" + count);
    clone.find("[id^='quantite']").attr("id", "quantite" + count);

    clone.insertAfter('#book-table tbody>tr:last');
    return false;
 });
```

});